# How to get a value from an array to be used in another class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, parameters, constructor

If there is an array such as:

```
//....
int[] anArray;
anArray = new int[3];
anArray[0] = new otherClassWConst( x, y , z);
anArray[1] = new otherClassWConst( x, y , z);
anArray[2] = new otherClassWConst( x, y , z);
//....
```

With the values of x and y and z all being of different value to the other x, y, and z's from the other objects in the array. (Does that make sense? Like the value of x in anArray[0] is not the same as the value found in anArray[2]). **Note: there is a constructor from another class that requires those parameters, I'm not sure if thats important**

How do I, in a different class, get the value of one of the parameters (for example, the value of y) in each of the array values. As in, is there a way I can get all three values of the Ys so I can add them all up together in another class?

For example

```
//code attaining only the y values of the array
overallValueOfY = Y + Y + Y; // or something of that nature
//life continues over here.
```

Please tell me if something is unclear, I tried so hard to explain. Thank you for the consideration.

Comment: Show your class structure.

Answer (score 0):

`OtherClassConst` will need to supply a get method for it:

```
public class OtherClassConst {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int x;

    public (int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    /* Same concept for getX() and getZ() */
}
```

Then, you class can call it:

```
int sumY = 0;
for (OtherClassConst c : myArray) {
    sumY += c.getY();
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an immutable object with `public final int` rather than `private int` variables and use `c.y` instead of `c.getY()`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your array won't work unless your new class extends Int, I just want to make sure you know that.

Now, all you have to do is in that new class create an int varriable

```
int x;
int y;
int z;
```

and set them equal to what is put in the constructor. Then create a new method that returns the values

```
public int getX(){
  return this.x;
}
public int getY(){
  return this.Y;
}
public int getZ(){
  return this.Z;
}
```

Comment: BTW, in case the OP does not know, you cannot subclass int, any primitive, or even Integer (which is final). Just making sure :-)

Comment: what does subclassing mean?

Comment: @RythianLombard it means extending a class. If you want one class to have all the properties of another you write "extends someClass" at the beginning. Your array right now is made for int but you are trying to fill it with some other class, so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `POJO` for your other class with x,y and z instance variables, then using setter method of y you can get the values. Iterate over them to get the sum of values.

Answer (score 0):

If you other `OtherClass` has a `getY` method that returns an integer then you can use the following to sum them:

```
Arrays.stream(anArray).mapToInt(OtherClass::getY).sum();
```

It is worth getting use to using streams rather than for loops.